# Batch file for starting powershell in a specific directory

Tags: windows, batch, powershell

I am learning to program in python through the book "Learn python the hard way".
Therefore I use powershell to run my programs.
Since I had to manually change the directory every-time I started powershell , I wrote a batch file to automate it.

The command I wrote is :

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "'cd c:\self\pooja\"edu n career"\programs\python'"
```

The problem is that it runs but opens the directory of "programs" only.
Why is it not changing to python directory?

Finally , I did it by setting the "Start in" field in the shortcut property of powershell but I want to know why the batch file is not working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close Nate, but that doesn't work when I run it on a "New Folder".  Had to move the CD outside the single quotes to make it work.

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd 'c:\New folder'"
powershell.exe -noexit -command "cd 'c:\self\pooja\edu n career\programs\python'"
```

Comment: I am trying to run the batch file again but cmd starts and closes immediately . I have written it same as you told.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what your directory folder looks like, but assuming that `edu n career` is one directory, you shouldn't need to escape that with its own set of double quotes, you should be able to change the code to

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command "'cd c:\self\pooja\edu n career\programs\python'"
```

If you look at the command in a text editor with syntax highlighting, you can see that the `edu n career` is actually not part of the command.

[image: code]